# How prevent page refresh with ASP.NET Ajax using Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to populate a second dropdownlist based on the index of the first.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
<Triggers >
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl1"    EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate >
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="1" />
<asp:ListItem Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ddl2.SelectedIndex = ddl1.SelectedIndex;
 }
```

I am getting a complete post back. No ajax at work.

Comment: you can set AutoPostBack='false` and from there you can create some JavaScript to handle what you are trying to do..

Comment: The code you have in ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged doesn't make sense as it "auto-select" and not "auto-populate". I hope you mean to populate the list from some data source.

Comment: As the title says... the problem is the page refresh.

Comment: Place your dropdown in update panel

Comment: So you want to populate ddl2 when ddl1 selected index change, without postback ?

Comment: Well I guess I should have asked earlier the follow up question, and it is, does dropping the UpdatePanel an option? Depends on what you're doing, if you're just selecting the index on the second dropdown you really don't need any postback or even an ajax call. If you need to do some server-side processing then you can achieve it via jquery. So what is it?

Comment: I guess he wants to go with update panel based on shared markup. And its working fine.

Comment: That's not my real code. The real one does essentially that. I know that using javascript  and ajax is a better solution, but for now, for this old page,  get this to work is all that I need.